# Can't update localStorage with new objects

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a very basic shopping cart that stores orders to the localStorage. I'm struggling right now to update my array with my new orders (come in as objects).

```
$scope.checkout = function (shoppingCart) {
    $('#checkoutModal').modal('show');
    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("session"));
    if (existingEntries == null) existingEntries = new Array();
    var entry = {
        ReferenceNumber: '4444-0' + rand,
        Amount: $scope.subTotal,
        Date: new Date(),
        Voided: false
    };
    localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
    // Save allEntries back to local storage
    existingEntries.push(entry);
    localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
};
```

I would love it if someone could somewhere point out where I'm blind!

Comment: Can you confirm that localStorage has enough space left?

Comment: I think the question needs a little more clarification but looking at the code provided you get the existingEntries with the key `session` and then restore it with the key `allEntries`. Seems to me existingEntries will always be null and a new array will be created but again we aren't seeing all the code. You don't use shoppingCart variable and I don't see where this `rand ` variable comes form. Some outer scope I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Is `session` a valid localStorage item? It seems you should be trying to get existingEntries from `allEntries` instead.